# ReactJS: querySelectorAll .map function not working as expected with State

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to push my querySelectorAll .map function to a React State Array but its not working as expected.

```js
const [affectedServices, setAffectedServices] = useState([]);

  function affectedTags() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active-tag")).map((tag) => {
      console.log(tag.innerHTML);
      setAffectedServices([tag.innerHTML]);
    });
  }
```

`console.log(tag.innerHTML)` will display all querySelected tags e.g.

Active tag 1
Active tag 2
Active tag 3

But when viewing the `affectedServices` state from React Dev tools, it only has one array which contains `Active tag 3`

Any ideas of what im doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.
I think I will works for you.

```
const [affectedServices, setAffectedServices] = useState([]);

  function affectedTags() {
    setAffectedServices(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active-tag")).map((tag) => {return tag.innerHTML})));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your really elegant solution. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to push the value in the array at every loop, and not just replacing the previous value by a new, can you try this ?

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("affectedServices ", affectedServices);
}, [affectedServices]);

function affectedTags() {
    let result = [];

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active-tag")).forEach((el) => {
      result.push(el);
    });

    setAffectedServices(result);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort here. its definitely a workable solution for sure :)